# Lexical Analyzer: Assembly to Java

Tags: java, assembly, token, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I am currently working on a small project that requires a lexical analyzer for Assembly to Java. I am having difficulty working out the cases for which to assign types to each tokens. The comments are easy, as they begin with ';' and continue until the end of a line, however for the others I am having great difficulty.

There are 5 basic categories I'd like to make, The mnemonic names, the labels, the addresses, the offsets, and the comments. I am trying to implement this using switch cases, and I set the first case to be comments, as I thought that would be the easiest to handle. My plan was to exhaust all possibilities and leave mnemonics for the default case, however, when trying to come up with a case for Labels, I am at a loss. I know that Labels are always the first column of a line, and I know that once I am within the case, I will just take the substring of the line from the beginning of the Label until a blank space, however my issue is coming up for a case for it. Do you think if else statements would be better in this case? Please give me your recommendations on how to implement this properly. Thank you all in advance for all the help, it is greatly appreciated. Please find the code I have so far below, as well as a sample input.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList; 


public class Lexer 
{
    public static enum Type
    { 
        //This Assembly code has 5 token types 
        MNUMONIC_NAMES, LABELS, ADDRESSES, OFFSETS, COMMENTS;
    } 
    
    public static class Token
    { 
        public final Type t; 
        public final String c; 
        
        //constructor (set type)
        public Token(Type t, String c) 
        { 
            this.t = t; 
            this.c = c;
        } 
        
        //toString
        public String toString() 
        { 
            if(t == Type.MNUMONIC_NAMES) 
            { 
                return "MNUMONIC_NAMES<" + c + ">";
            } 
            
            if(t == Type.LABELS) 
            { 
                return "LABELS<" + c + ">";
            }  
            
            if(t == Type.ADDRESSES) 
            { 
                return "ADDRESSES<" + c + ">";
            } 
            
            if(t == Type.OFFSETS) 
            { 
                return "OFFSETS<" + c + ">";
            } 
            
            if(t == Type.COMMENTS) 
            { 
                return "COMMENTS<" + c + ">";
            } 
            
            return t.toString();
        }
    } 
    
    //Given a String and an index, get the mnumonic starting at index
    public static String getMNUMONIC_NAMES(String s, int i) 
    { 
        int j = i; 
        for(;j < s.length(); ) 
        { 
            //while character is a letter, continue
            if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(j)) ) 
            { 
                j++;
            } 
            else 
            { 
                return s.substring(i, j);
            }
        } 
        return s.substring(i,j);
    }  
    
    //Given a String and an index, get the comment starting at index
        public static String getComment(String s, int i) 
        { 
            int j = i; 
            for(;j < s.length(); ) 
            { 
                //continues until end of line
                if(s.charAt(j) != '\n') 
                { 
                    j++;
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    return s.substring(i, j);
                }
            } 
            return s.substring(i,j);
        }  
        
        
        //Given a String and an index, get the label starting at index
                public static String getLabel(String s, int i) 
                { 
                    int j = i; 
                    for(;j < s.length(); ) 
                    { 
                        //while character is a letter, continue
                        if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(j)) )  
                        { 
                            j++;
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                            return s.substring(i, j);
                        }
                    } 
                    return s.substring(i,j);
                } 
    
    public static List<Token> lex(String input)
    {
        List<Token> result = new ArrayList<Token>(); 
        for(int i = 0;i < input.length();) 
        { 
            switch(input.charAt(i)) 
            {  
                //case comment
                case ';': 
                    String comment = getComment(input, i); 
                    i+=comment.length();
                    result.add(new Token(Type.COMMENTS, comment)); 
                case '
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd say you have to keep a list of all possible mnemonics and test per line, if the first symbol is a mnemonic. If not, it is a label, but the next must be a mnemonic, else syntax error. why not use a parser generator like [Antlr](https://www.antlr.org/) and use its scanner?

Comment: e.g. here are the scanner/parser [rules](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/pdp7/pdp7.g4) for pdp-7 assembly to get an idea. When you do it by hand, you'd typically use a state machine, that decides per character what's going on.

Comment: [this guy](http://www.dmitry-kazakov.de/ada/components.htm#Parsers_etc) is a fan of hand writing that stuff it seems, shows lots of details and code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, for the sake of understanding how lexical analyzers work, I am coding this one by hand, and the project is not anything industrial or very large, so writing it by hand is not too complicated.